# How to avoid having to numerically identify each block in the experiment element in Inquisit?

Tags: inquisit

I often code a study in Inquisit where the study involves running a sequence of blocks. I express the order of the blocks in the form `1=...`, `2=...`, etc. See the example below.

```
<expt foostudy>
/blocks=[1=demographics; 2=cogtask; 3=spatialtask]
</expt>
```

However, it is a hassle when you have many blocks, and you want to add a block in the middle. All the numbers need to be updated.

Is there a way to not have to specify the numbers (e.g., 1, 2, 3) and just let the block order be implied from the sequence they are written?

E.g., Although the following does not work, I'm interested in something like:

```
<expt foostudy>
/blocks=[demographics; cogtask; spatialtask]
</expt>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to  use the `sequence(...)` command. I.e., write `1=sequence(...)` and place the ordered list of block names between the parentheses separated by commas.

So for the example it would be:

```
<expt foostudy>
/blocks=[1=sequence(demographics, cogtask, spatialtask)]
</expt>
```